# Factory with switch over enum that instantiates templates

Tags: c++, templates, design-patterns, factory, c++03

I have the following hierarchy pattern in various places in the codebase:

```
enum DerivedType {
    A, B, C };

class Base {
public:
  static Base* Create(DerivedType t);
};

template <DerivedType T>
class Derived : public Base {
};
```

The `Create` method returns a new object of class `Derived<A>`, `Derived<B>`, or  `Derived<C>`, depending on its argument:

```
Base* Base::Create(DerivedType t) {
  switch (t) {
  case A: return new Derived<A>;
  case B: return new Derived<B>;
  case C: return new Derived<C>;
  default: return NULL;
  }
}
```

The problem is that there are many such `Base -> Derived` hierarchies, with essentially the same implementation of `Create()` copy-pasted all over the place. Is there an elegant, yet easy-to-understand way to avoid duplication here?

Answer (score 2):

We can abstract away the Factory details, and rely on the client to provide us the mapping of enum to class type:

```
template<typename ENUM, typename T>
struct Factory
{
    typedef std::map<ENUM, T*(*)()> map_type;
    static map_type factoryMapping_;

    static T* Create(ENUM c)
    {
        return factoryMapping_[c]();
    }

    static void Init(map_type _mapping)
    {
        factoryMapping_ = _mapping;
    }
};

template<typename ENUM, typename T>
typename Factory<ENUM, T>::map_type Factory<ENUM,T>::factoryMapping_;
```

Now it's the client's job to provide us methods for creating a `Base*` given some enum value.

If you're willing and able to abstract away the creation of a derived class with a template, then you can save a fair bit of typing.

What I mean is, let's create a templated function to create a derived class (without any real checking for correctness):

```
template<typename Base, typename Derived>
Base* CreateDerived()
{
    return new Derived();
}
```

Now I can define an enum and associated class hierarchy:

```
enum ClassType {A, B};
struct Foo
{
    virtual void PrintName() const
    {
        std::cout << "Foo\n";
    }
};

typedef Factory<ClassType, Foo> FooFactory ;

struct DerivedOne : public Foo
{
    virtual void PrintName() const
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedOne\n";
    }
};

struct DerivedTwo : public Foo
{
    virtual void PrintName() const
    {
        std::cout << "DerivedTwo\n";
    }
};
```

And then use it like so:

```
// set up factory
std::map<ClassType, Foo*(*)()> mapping;
mapping[A] = &CreateDerived<Foo, DerivedOne>;
mapping[B] = &CreateDerived<Foo, DerivedTwo>;
FooFactory::Init(mapping);

// Use the factory
Foo* f = FooFactory::Create(A);
f->PrintName();
```

### [Live Demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/46076a7da72294a3)

Of course this simplifies your problem a bit, namely moving the factory details out of the base class and ignoring for a minute that the children themselves are templated. Depending on how hard it is in your domain to create a good `CreateDerived` function for each type, you may not end up saving a ton of typing.

**EDIT**: We can modify our `Create` function to return NULL by taking advantage of [std::map::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/find). I omitted it for brevity. If you concerned about performance, then yes, an O(log n) search is slower asymptotically than a simple switch, but I strongly doubt this will wind up being the hot path.

Answer (score 1):

You could make it a template

```
template<typename Base, typename Derive, template<Derive> class Derived>
Base* Base::Create(Derive t) {
  switch (t) {
  case Derive::A: return new Derived<Derive::A>;
  case Derive::B: return new Derived<Derive::B>;
  case Derive::C: return new Derived<Derive::C>;
  default: return nullptr;
  }
}
```

but that assumes that there are only ever `A`, `B`, and `C` in `struct enum Derive`.

Comment: Thanks. Is this compatible with C++03? How would that work with only one template argument for `Create`?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using a C++ style enum you could use a Java style enum where each value is a singleton of a class derived from a common base.

Then define a set of pure virtual functions on the base class that create the desired flavour of derived class, and implement them appropriately in each of the singletons.

Then instead of `switch (t) ...` you can use `t->createDerived()`.

Or to put it more succinctly: replace switch with polymorphism.

Comment: Thanks. I'd still need at least one switch(t), because I still get plain old enums as input. That's fine, I guess. Would you like to sketch an implementation for two Base -> Derived hierarchies?

Comment: Not really; I have every confidence you can fill in the detail.